# Prove that the sequence $f_n(x)=x^nf(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ iff $f(1)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the sequence $f_n(x)=x^nf(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ iff $f(1)=0$.

Since $f_n$ is uniformly convergent, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \rightarrow \epsilon$

And so $|x^nf(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

How do we deduce $f(1)=0$

And how do we prove the other side assuming$f(1)=0$?

Comment: What kind of question is this?!  Where are assumptions on $f$?  First learn how to write a precise question then expect for answers !

Comment: This is the whole question as written by my professor..

Comment: So then show the below counter example to your genius professor.
I think $f$ must be continuous, at least at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

What about $f(x)= 0$ for $x \in [0, 1)$, and $f(1)=1$. 
Then $f_n(x)= f(x)$ for all $x \in [0 ,1]$ which is clearly uniform convergent to $f$ !